# add two input parameters in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

to add two input numbers using stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure add
(num1 in int,num2 in int)is
begin
declare output int;
set output:=num1 + num2 
dbms_output.enable();
dbms_output.put_line(output);
end add;
```

i need to add two inpuut parameters

```
begin;
add(5,5)
end;
```

result :

```
10
```

i have come up with this code getting error while compiling the procedure

i am using oracle 10g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_TWO_INPUT (N1 IN NUMBER,N2 IN NUMBER)
IS
ADD_RESULT NUMBER;
BEGIN
ADD_RESULT := N1 + N2;
Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE(ADD_RESULT);
END;
/


EXECUTE ADD_TWO_INPUT(1,2);
```

output:-

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

- it looks `add` is reserved: it is not possible to use it as a procedure name
- You do not need this `set` thing, and `declare` must go too:

---

```
create or replace procedure add_ (num1 in int,num2 in int) is
  output int;
begin
  output:=num1 + num2 ;
  dbms_output.enable();
  dbms_output.put_line(output);
end add_;
/
```

Then how to call it:

```
exec add_(5,5)
```

or  (do not forget the `;` and `/` in `sqlplus`)

```
begin; 
  add(5,5);
end;
/
```

Comment: changed the procedure name now error on line 4 encountered symbol "="   @j.chomel